# Find duplicate classes in list item - .filter() show them, hide the rest

Tags: jquery

I am working on a code that will display list items in a unordered list that have duplicate `<li class="duplicate duplicate">` and hide all the rest. Basically a filter. The elemets are generated by other portion of my code which is irrelevant in this example, I do not know how I could accomplish this.

## The first scenario

Display all duplicates ( only classes that repeat more then once )

## Second scenario

Display all duplicates of a given class ( can have other classes too : like red red blue )

Here is a example : http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/233350/ this includes only filtering specific values

```js
var show_red = $("#show_red");
var duplicates = $("#duplicates");
var reset = $("#reset");

show_red.on("click", function(){
  
 var rows = $(".myList").find(".list_entry");
 $(".list_entry").hide().filter(".red").show();
            
});

reset.on("click", function(){
  
 var rows = $(".myList").find(".list_entry");
 $(".list_entry").show();
            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="duplicates">Display Duplicates</button>
<button id="show_red">Show Only Red</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

</button>

<ul class="myList">
<li class="list_entry  red red blue 1">Element1</li>
<li class="list_entry  red blue blue 2">Element2</li>
<li class="list_entry  pink 3">Element3</li>
<li class="list_entry  orange orange 4">Element4</li>
<li class="list_entry  black white 5">Element5</li>
<li class="list_entry  white white 6">Element6</li>
<li class="list_entry  black orange 7">Element7</li>
<li class="list_entry  test 8">Element8</li>
<li class="list_entry  something something 9">Element9</li>
<li class="list_entry  single 10">Element10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'd have to find all the elements, and do a custom filter, checking each class in the class list to see if it is in there multiple times.  A better question would be why is your markup being generated like this in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? You mean the class is written twice? e.g. `red red` ?

Comment: Yes that classes that appears more then once, I am not sure how to start this code since the class names are dynamic.

Comment: If the classes are not being used for styling, it would be better to utilize a `data-` attribute to hold the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $rows = $(".myList").find(".list_entry");

$("#show_red").on("click", function() {
  $rows.hide().filter(".red").show();
});

$("#reset").on("click", function() {
  $rows.show();
});

function uniqueValues ( array ) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, value){
    if (result.indexOf(value) < 0) result.push(value);
    
    return result;
  }, []);
}

$("#duplicates").on('click', function() {
  $rows.hide().filter(function(){
    //get the classes, ignoring repeated whitespace
    var classes = this.getAttribute('class').split(/\s+/);
    //get the unique classes
    var uniqueClasses = uniqueValues(classes);
    //return true if the unique classes are less than the classes
    return classes.length != uniqueClasses.length;
  }).show();
});

$('.show_duplicate').on('click', function () {
  //get the specific class we want to show duplicates for
  var targetClass = this.getAttribute('data-color');
  
  $rows.hide().filter(function(){
    //get the classes, ignoring repeated whitespace
    var classes = this.getAttribute('class').split(/\s+/);
    //get count of targetClass
    var classCount = classes.filter(function(className){ return className === targetClass; }).length;
    //return true if the unique classes are less than the classes
    //and the specific class appears multiple times
    return classCount > 1;
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="duplicates">Display Duplicates</button>
<button id="show_red">Show Only Red</button>
<button class="show_duplicate" data-color="red">Show Duplicate Red</button>
<button class="show_duplicate" data-color="white">Show Duplicate White</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<ul class="myList">
  <li class="list_entry  red red blue 1">Element1</li>
  <li class="list_entry  red blue blue 2">Element2</li>
  <li class="list_entry  pink 3">Element3</li>
  <li class="list_entry  orange orange 4">Element4</li>
  <li class="list_entry  black white 5">Element5</li>
  <li class="list_entry  white white 6">Element6</li>
  <li class="list_entry  black orange 7">Element7</li>
  <li class="list_entry  test 8">Element8</li>
  <li class="list_entry  something something 9">Element9</li>
  <li class="list_entry  single 10">Element10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft I added the logic for filtering duplicates for a given color.  If you want any additional functionality added, please open another question.

Comment: Sure will do can't accept both of you answers I struggle :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865639/multifilter-logic-using-list-items this is some really hard stuff for me :) not sure if even can be done

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's not strictly valid to have the same classname twice on the same element; if you check the element's classList you'll see that the duplicate classes have been removed.

Fortunately we can make use of that behavior to detect the presence of duplicate classnames without having to directly test the array for uniqueness: just compare the number of classes in the classList, and the number in the raw attribute value.

```js
$('#duplicates').on("click", function() {
  $(".list_entry")
    .show()
    .each(function() {
      var x = this.classList.value.split(/\s+/);
      var y = this.classList;
      if (x.length === y.length) { // no duplicates
        $(this).hide() 
      }
    })
})

$('#reset').on("click",function() {
  $('.list_entry').show()
})
$('#show_red').on("click",function() {
  $('.list_entry').hide()
  $('.list_entry.red').show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="duplicates">Display Duplicates</button>
<button id="show_red">Show Only Red</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>



<ul class="myList">
  <li class="list_entry  red red blue 1">Element1</li>
  <li class="list_entry  red blue blue 2">Element2</li>
  <li class="list_entry  pink 3">Element3</li>
  <li class="list_entry  orange orange 4">Element4</li>
  <li class="list_entry  black white 5">Element5</li>
  <li class="list_entry  white white 6">Element6</li>
  <li class="list_entry  black orange 7">Element7</li>
  <li class="list_entry  test 8">Element8</li>
  <li class="list_entry  something something 9">Element9</li>
  <li class="list_entry  single 10">Element10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am aware that its not good but they are used to filter my staff =) so it has to have duplicates in some cases, they do not influecene any styling at all. I will try both answers for sure. This is the first step. Another would be find only red duplicates only.

Comment: The answers are very similar; the only significant difference is that I'm cheating a bit by counting on the classList to do the work of deduplicating the classnames while Taplar is doing it manually.  (Which is fine, too, of course.)

Comment: As I wrote, if I would like add extra logic as show specific class duplicates would wrap up my project. f.e duplicates of red

Comment: That would require something closer to Taplar's approach; mine can only tell you that there are duplicates, not which ones they are -- ("blue blue red" would show up as both "has duplicates" and "has red", which probably isn't what you want.)

Comment: (In general, please don't significantly change the subject of a question after it's already been answered, especially by making additional requests in comments where future users are unlikely to see them.  Either post a separate question or include everything in the question in the first place.)

Comment: My bad, added two scenarios

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865639/multifilter-logic-using-list-items continuation if you want to participate much appreciated