# Multifilter logic using list items

Tags: jquery

The following code will search any duplicate classes `<li class="duplicate duplicate">` in a list item within an unordered list and it will display the results `.show()` and `.hide()` all the rest.

## Current version

It currently works in two scenarios

## First

It is displaying any list items that have the same class ( at least one or more ).

## Second

Displays the list items class duplicates but we can specific which class will it be. For example find and display duplicates of class .red

I have everything set and going.

```js
var $rows = $(".myList").find(".list_entry");

$("#show_red").on("click", function() {
  $rows.hide().filter(".red").show();
});

$("#reset").on("click", function() {
  $rows.show();
});

function uniqueValues ( array ) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, value){
    if (result.indexOf(value) < 0) result.push(value);
    
    return result;
  }, []);
}

$("#duplicates").on('click', function() {
  $rows.hide().filter(function(){
    //get the classes, ignoring repeated whitespace
    var classes = this.getAttribute('class').split(/\s+/);
    //get the unique classes
    var uniqueClasses = uniqueValues(classes);
    //return true if the unique classes are less than the classes
    return classes.length != uniqueClasses.length;
  }).show();
});

$('.show_duplicate').on('click', function () {
  //get the specific class we want to show duplicates for
  var targetClass = this.getAttribute('data-color');
  
  $rows.hide().filter(function(){
    //get the classes, ignoring repeated whitespace
    var classes = this.getAttribute('class').split(/\s+/);
    //get count of targetClass
    var classCount = classes.filter(function(className){ return className === targetClass; }).length;
    //return true if the unique classes are less than the classes
    //and the specific class appears multiple times
    return classCount > 1;
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="duplicates">Display Duplicates</button>
<button id="show_red">Show Only Red</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

</button>

<ul class="myList">
    <li class="list_entry  red red blue class1"><span style="border-color:red;"></span><span style="border-color:red;"></span><span style="border-color: blue;"></span></li>
    <li class="list_entry  red red orange class1A"><span style="color:red;"></span><span style="border-color:red;"></span><span style="color:orange;"></span></li>
    <li class="list_entry  red blue blue class2"><span style="color:red;"></span><span style="color:blue;"></span><span style="color:blue;"></span></li>
    <li class="list_entry  pink class3"><span style="color:pink;"></span></li>
    <li class="list_entry  orange orange red class4"><span style="color:orange;"></span><span style="color:orange;"></span><span style="color:red;"></span></li>
    <li class="list_entry  black white class5"><span style="color:grey;"></span><span style="color:black;"></span></li>
    <li class="list_entry  white white class6"><span style="color:grey;"></span><span style="color:grey;"></span></li>
    <li class="list_entry  black orange class7"><span style="color:black;"></span><span style="color:orange;"></span></li>
</ul>
<style>
span{
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
}

li{
    margin:15px;
}
</style>
```

## What I do want to achieve

## Real example ( gaming example ):

We have a set of buttons that will filter the list items. The list items will be filtered by the class attributes.

## Example filter buttons

```
Leveling filters : Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4, Level_5
Rewards : Experience, AnotherTypeOfExperience, AndAnotherExp
AdditionalRewards : Item1, Item2, Item3
MissionZone : City, Suburbs
MissionType : Defence, Offense
```

Example of an `<li class="Level_1 City Defence Item1 Item1 Item3"></li>`

User selects following filters examples :

```
Show me (Level_1 OR City OR Defence AND) Item1 OR Item3
Show me (Level_1 AND) Duplicates Of Item1
Show me (Level_2 OR Defence AND) Item2
Show me (Level_1 AND City AND) Item2 OR Duplicates of Item2
```

General idea : `Show me (Leveling filters $filter_logic MissionZone $filter_logic MissionType (AND -fixed)) Rewards $filter_logic Rewards/AdditionalRewards`

So Leveling filters, MissionZone, MissionType is filter set 1
the reward filters are the filter set 2.

## example 1

```
filterset1 = [level_1,city];
filterset2 = [Item1,Duplicates];
$filter_logic = AND;

    show : (Level_1 AND City) 1 AND (Item1 AND Duplicates)
             |                   /\            | 
          filterset1         fixed AND    filterset2
```

## example 2

```
 filterset1 = [level_1,city];
filterset2 = [Item1,Duplicates];
$filter_logic = AND;

    show : (Level_1 OR City) 1 AND Item1 OR Duplicates
                        |       /\            | 
          filterset1         fixed AND    filterset2
```

I do not know how to even start this. If you got any hints please share them.

Comment: Trying to get a grasp on what you are asking for.  So are you trying to make it so that the user can choose which classes they want to check for if there are dupes, and you want to be able to specify if the elements should have dupes for both the classes, or any of the classes?

Comment: So my first thought then is that sorta describes two separate input elements of some fashion.  One to choose the class(es), and another to choose between AND and OR.  I might suggest that you break down this problem into multiple questions.  It's pretty broad at this point.

Comment: Everything can be a variable.  The point is you will have to have a user interface for the user to select which operation they want to do.  Otherwise a variable that the user can't change isn't really an "option", eh? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173176/discussion-between-kavvson-empcraft-and-taplar).

Comment: @Taplar started an bounty on this one

Comment: I would consider clarifying your post because its so messy that you will hardly find someone willing to help/understand what you wrote

Comment: maybe you are looking for a syntax to model logic expressions.. but I can't be sure because correctly understanding your issue requires too much efforts